# Powershell - Bitbucket

Tags: json, powershell, bitbucket

I'm probably missing something really simple here.  I have the following powershell with nested jsons on the body.

`Invoke-RestMethod  "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/myworkspace/$slug" -Body @{ "scm" = "git"; "project" = @{ "key" = $pkey }; } -Method Post -Headers @{Authorization = $cloudAuthHeader}`

But the response I'm getting from the server is:

`Invoke-RestMethod : {"type": "error", "error": {"fields": {"project": ["Project must be an object with a \"key\" or \"uuid\" property."]}, "message": "project: Project must be an object  with a \"key\" or \"uuid\" property."}}`

As far as I can tell, project is an object with a "key" property...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
$body = @{ "scm" = "git"; "project" = @{ "key" = $pkey }; } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
$auth = @{Authorization = $cloudAuthHeader} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Afaik if you don't convert it to JSON it is still a PowerShell object.

Invoke-RestMethod:

```
"https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/myworkspace/$slug" -Body $body -Method Post -Headers $auth
```